# Invalid response at function call from time to time

Tags: json-rpc, uniswap, geth-debugging, ethers.js, bsc

I am continuously trying to fetch all pair addresses from a PancakeSwap contract but while doing so it always fails after some time saying:

```
Error: invalid response - 0
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/Users/paulus/node_modules/ethers/utils/web.js:84:29)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/Users/paulus/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
    at setState (/Users/paulus/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.handleError (/Users/paulus/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:532:5)
    at ClientRequest.errorHandler (/Users/paulus/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:459:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:462:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3) {
  statusCode: 0,
  responseText: 'Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bsc-dataseed3.defibit.io\n' +
    '    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26)'
}
```

Also I didn't recognize any patterns which means it fails at different points and the time intervals also vary. My function to get all the addresses looks like this:

```
async function fetchPairAddresses2() {
    const allPairsLength = await pancakeFactory.allPairsLength()
    let alreadyFetched = pancakePairs.length

    for (let i = alreadyFetched; i < allPairsLength; i++) {
        let pairAddress = pancakeFactory.allPairs(i)
        writeToFile(await pairAddress)
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Maybe I could switch the RPC when such an error occurs but I don't know how I could do that if it is possible.

**EDIT:**
There should be no problem with my internet connection cause when I cut my connection I get an other error:

```
Error timeout
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/paulus/node_modules/ethers/utils/web.js:54:20)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

Comment: It seems a problem with your internet connection.

Comment: No I don't think so... I have cut the connection and this gives me an other error -> I edited the question please have a look

Comment: Search for the error message `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`.